# Перегрузка оператора для разных классов

Tags: c++

Например у меня есть своя структура Vector3

```
struct Vector3
{
  int x, y, z;
  Vector3() {}
  Vector3(int x, int y, int z): x(x),y(y),z(z) 
  {}
};
```

и я перегружу оператор сложения

```
Vector3 operator + (const Vector3 &v1, const Vector3 &v2)
{ return Vector3(v1.x + v2.x, v1.y + v2.y, v1.z + v2.z); }

Vector3& operator = (const Vector3 &v)
{ if (*this!=v)
  {
    this->x = v.x;
    this->y = v.y
    this->z = v.z;
   }
   return *this;
 }

Vector3 vec1(2,2,2), vec2(4,1,2);

Vector3 vec3 = vec1 + vec2;

// Все вроде как норм
```

Все вроде бы норм, если не ошибся, но суть понятна. Определил для моей структуры два оператора, а что насчет, если бы я складывал свой тип с каким нибудь другим. Например, мой вектор + `std::vector<>`. Как это реализовать? И как компилятор видит, какой метод нужно использовать. Как он понимает, что надо , например, когда я складывал два вектора использовать мой метод.

Comment: Что мешает вместо Vector3 указать std::vector? Компилятор определяет по типам аргументов необходимую функцию

Comment: В вашем примере `operator =`  не используется и роли не играет.  В любом случае, определять оператор присваивания вручную для такого объекта нет никакого смысла - компилятор сам его правильно определит. Также, оператот рисваивания обязан быть членом класса.

Answer (score 1):

### Есть два способа, через перегрузку оператора сложения и через дополнительный конструктор.

**Способ 1.**

Вы можете определить оператор сложения с `std::vector<>` :

```
Vector3 operator + (const Vector3 &v1, const std::vector<int> &v2)
{
    if (v2.size() != 3)
    {
        throw std::string("v2 is not 3-dimensional vector!");
    }
    return Vector3(v1.x + v2[0], v1.y + v2[1], v1.z + v2[2]);
}
```

**Способ 2.**

Определить дополнительный конструктор:

```
Vector3(const std::vector<int> &vec)
{
    if (vec.size() != 3)
    {
        throw std::string("vec is not 3-dimensional vector!");
    }
    else
    {
        x = vec[0];
        y = vec[1];
        z = vec[2];
    }
}
```

**PS.** Если используете второй метод, обратите внимание, что конструктор объявлен **без** ключевого слова `explicit`.

**PS2.** У вас небольшая ошибка в реализации оператора присваивания:

```
Vector3& operator = (const Vector3 &v)
{
    if (this != &v)
    {
        this->x = v.x;
        this->y = v.y
        this->z = v.z;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

В `if` нужно сравнивать именно указатели, а не объекты.

Comment: А что за v2 во втором методе самая первая проверка. Это вектор собственной структуры, а почему именно v2

Comment: Это была опечатка, конечно, там должно быть `vec` вместо `v2`.

Comment: Второй метод я описываю в самом struct ? Если да, то как это работает, если нет, то тот же вопрос, как этот метод работает

Comment: Да, в самой структуре. А работает это так, вы пытаетесь сложить `v1 + v2` , `v1` тут это `Vector3` , а `v2` это `std::vector<int>`, комилятор не находит оператор сложения `Vector3` и `std::vector<int>` (но находит оператор сложения двух `Vector3`), зато находит конструктор `Vector3` из `std::vector<int>`, тогда он неявно преобразует `v2` в `Vector3` и вызывает оператор сложения `Vector3` с `Vector3`. Примерно так.

Comment: А вот в if надо сравнивать указатели, this это указатель, а &v - это не ссылка? или как то все по другому работает?

Comment: `&v` это указатель, а не ссылка.

Comment: Я скорее всего чего то не понимаю. В данном случае это указатель, или он всегда указатель.  // структура объявления ссылок
/*тип*/ &/*имя ссылки*/ = /*имя переменной*/; Это я из сайта скопировал. Или когда я передаю в какой нибудь метод ссылку &object, и потом в самом методе использую &object, то это уже будет как указателЬ?

Comment: /*тип*/ &/*имя ссылки*/ - это объявление ссылки, например `int &x = y;`, получилась ссылка `x` на переменную `y`, а если так: `int *x;`, то `x` - указатель, его можно инициализировать адресом: `x = &y;`, оператор `&` перед ранее созданной переменной возвращает её адрес, указатель на неё.